# Scala JDBC connection:java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc

I have imported

```
scala> import java.sql._
scala> Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

Next step is to connect to database server

```
scala> val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test",
"milenko", // username when connecting
"papai" // password)
```

But problems occured with

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'milenko'@'localhost'
  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
```

My connections

```
netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:31416           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this connection. Does this user exists? Does this user have privileges for the action your are trying?

Comment: @ManishMishra I am leanrnin scala,try to connect to server.Can you write an answer on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using localhost the coonection works.
msebaapc:bin sebaacomtx$ ./mysql -u root -p mysql-admin -h
localhost -P 3306
Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor. Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 97
Server version: 5.6.15 MySQL Community Server (GPL)